# Pros/cons: custom build rackets (for hobby/casual players)

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket

I'm considering whether or not it's worth the time or the money to invest in getting parts and put together a racket for a hobby/casual player. I am not horrible in the sport but it's pretty obvious I'll never compete in a respectable tournament. :)

So my question is all the fuss about equipment, how much of it would be useful for a player like myself and how much is marketing mumbo-jumbo? Of course it's impossible to give a quantitative measure to it, but I was wondering if there are other casual players who did end up buying better equipment (~100+ euros) and whether or not there was a difference to their overall gameplay.

Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain his/her motivation for the down-vote?

Comment: I didn't vote you down (voted you up back to 0) but they don't like shopping questions.

Comment: I'm also voting to close. My suggestion would be to rephrase asking about the benefits of custom paddles rather than a "is it worth it" which is entirely subjective and not exactly constructive.

Comment: your suggestion is fair, and I can go along with the edit. However I do not think this question is a "shopping question" as I am not asking for a brand/model comparison. All I wonder is if there are people out there who might have experience on the matter, and if according to their experience it's a sound investment. If it turns out that you need to have a pretty advance level to make good use of more expensive equipment that's rather valuable piece of information for casual players like myself. I'll edit the question title...

Comment: Hmm, I read "custom build rockets" and wondered why it was on Sports.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was competing at school I built my own one, and the end result not only felt just like one of the better ones I could buy, it cost me about the same.

It also took me a lot of time and effort to ensure the layers were correctly affixed and smoothed.

This is a very small statistical sample, but I would suggest buying a nice bat that feels good to you.

Comment: So you're suggesting that it's not worth that hassle, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Correct - unless you really want to do it, I wouldn't bother.